# Проставление значений по условию в другом столбце при сложном условии

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
    ...                          "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
    ...                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
    ...                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
    ...                    "C": ["2017", "2017", "2018", "2017",
    ...                          "2018", "2017", "2018", "2017",
    ...                          "2017"],
    ...                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
```

1. Необходимо проставить в столбец 'E' значения 'Yes' если в строке A содержится 'f' и в столбце 'B' значение равное 'one'
2. Необходимо проставить в столбец 'D' значение 'No' если выполнение некой функции возвращает True.
3. Необходимо проставить в столбец 'F' значения по условию из словаря, если ключ словаря входит в строку то возвращаем значение по ключу.

Comment: Во-первых, никакого сложного условия не наблюдается. Во-вторых, в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: df['E'] = np.where(df['A'].str.contains('fo'), 'Yes', 'No') - данную конструкцию мне предложили в предыдущем вопросе при одном условии. Но сейчас условий несколько и эту конструкцию не могу применить.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: хочу получить заполененный столбец в дата фрейме в соответствии с условиями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# 1
df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('f') & (df['B'] == 'one'), 'E'] = 'Yes'

# 2
def func(ser):
    return ser % 2 == 0

df.loc[func(df['D']), 'D'] = 'No'
```

Третий пункт без примера словаря и того что должно получиться на выходе непонятен...

Результат:

```
In [251]: df
Out[251]:
     A    B     C   D    E
0  foo  one  2017   1  Yes
1  foo  one  2017  No  Yes
2  foo  one  2018  No  Yes
3  foo  two  2017   3  NaN
4  foo  two  2018   3  NaN
5  bar  one  2017  No  NaN
6  bar  one  2018   5  NaN
7  bar  two  2017  No  NaN
8  bar  two  2017   7  NaN
```